# Trying to find a Sci Fi book about a man in love with the captain's daughter put in charge of hydroponics

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a book that was a favorite of a friend of mine, who is elderly and blind.  She was recounting the plot to me but I couldn't find any matches searching.  She said it was like a series of short stories, written in the 1950s or 60s.

The plot is that this guy joined a spaceship because he was in love with the captain's daughter.
They first put him in charge of the kitchen, cooking for the crew and everyone loved his food.  Next they put him in charge of hydroponics and everything grew wildly.  He eventually got together with the captain's daughter.

Any ideas? I would love to find this book to read to her.

Comment: So this was an anthology book?

Comment: @user14111: To flip your question around, what makes you think that the OP’s use of “ship” isn’t referring to a spaceship?

Comment: @RLH Because the default meaning of the English word "ship" is not spaceship or airship, any more than the default meaning of "horse" is sawhorse or seahorse. The default meaning of "ship" is "large seagoing vessel." If the ship in question was  in outer space instead of at sea, that would seem too important a point to leave out of a story description.

Comment: @user14111 "Ship" as "spaceship" is commonly enough used that the OP's use of "ship" seemed clear from context. Your question reads as pedantic sarcasm directed towards a new contributor, especially with the bold text. (Something like "To confirm, this is a spaceship rather than a seagoing vessel, right?" would have prompted the OP for clarification without attacking them.)

Comment: @user14111, I did mean spaceship... Apparently, I should have been more precise!  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @LogicDictates I'm not sure.  My friend is now in her 80's, and read the story 50+ years ago, so I'm not sure how accurate her memory is about the details of the story or format.